# How To Stop Rejecting Messages At Low Memory?

Tags: motorola-droid, internal-storage, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't receive SMS when I have low storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/i-cant-receive-sms-when-i-have-low-storage)

When my phone reaches ~22Mb (internal) free space, my phone starts to automatically reject text messages.  Assuming they're on internal storage, can the storage location somehow be changed to external storage?

Comment: I wonder if a third-party SMS app might help -- but installing one wouldn't help with your limited storage problem.  [This question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/merging-multiple-sms-databases) has the location of the database, and [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/i-cant-receive-sms-on-my-motorola-milestone-when-internal-storage-is-almost-full) covers trying to disable the "feature".  I'm going to edit your question to just be about moving the storage location, if that's OK.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks again for your help.  I'll see if I can muster up such an app.

Comment: Are you sure that it's because the phone is low on free space, or could it be related to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12326/sms-thread-message-total-doesnt-increase-past-201)?

Comment: I actually went through and deleted all of my messages.  Since that didn't clear up much space, the problem persisted.  I appreciate the link though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known and reported bug from 2009. ( See the [answer to my question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/17370/1262) )

[Google says](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4991#c257) they fixed it in Android 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, as far as my knowledge goes there does not exist an SMS app which automatically receives it and stores it on SD card, but there does exist a SMS backup feature which creates a backup of the inbox onto the SD card.

You'll have to uninstall some apps to free up space to receive more messages. Not much else you can do about this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip CustomiZer.  I just can't believe that with over 20Mb (~20% free) I cannot receive a message that's a few Kb in size.  I can see why there's this check, but it definitely should be customizable.  Really, the only thing I have installed on the internal is updates to build in apps (Google Maps, etc).  Maybe I'll just to solder in a new memory chip, it'll give me an excuse to buy a new phone :-)

Comment: If you wonder about the 20 MB See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4991#c145 (Android keeps as much free space as the biggest App you installed takes up so that you can still update it. So if you've got Opera installed (which is quite big with 22MB or something?), you need to have more than those some 22MB of free space left.)