# SMS thread message total doesn't increase past 201

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sms

I have a Samsung Galaxy S running firmware version 2.2 with pretty much the default configuration it came with from the shop. On it, the `(Unread/All)` counter with one of my contacts has been stuck at `(0/201)` for quite a while, even though I've been sending more messages to the contact in question so the `All` value should be increasing at the very least.

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea how to get this to refresh so it shows the updated total?  Or is this a hard limit set somewhere or something like that?

Comment: Note: I tagged it with the phone just in case, I'm not sure whether it actually has to do with the model.

Comment: Strange bug, but ... does it matter if the # unread is working?

Comment: The number was not changing regardless...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because there's a threshold beyond which it starts deleting old messages. Go into messaging, hit the menu button & go to settings. The first option is `Delete old messages` (checked by default), and the next is `Text message limit` (set to 200 by default). So you've just hit that threshold & it's deleting your old messages.