# How to edit and merge two different sms backup from two different phone?

Tags: sms, backup

I have my SMS backed up using SMS Backup and Restore, and also my girlfriend's SMS was backed up using the BlackBerry Desktop tool.

I converted the BB SMS back up to an `.xml` file.

I just want to know how can I edit the converted back up (from BB) so that the sender will be me, because due to unfortunate crashing of my SMS app, some texts are deleted.

So I want to restore that deleted text but from my GF's SMS and merge it to my backed up (Android) file. How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post the format(not contents) of the BB SMS which you converted into `.xml` file? and This question might be helpful? [Merging multiple SMS databases](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/merging-multiple-sms-databases?rq=1)

Comment: The file of the BB SMS back up is .bbb. I used Blakberry 2 Droid to convert it to .xml. That question does not solve my problem. I have a non-rooted device and I only used the SMS Backup and Restore app.